# Is it possible to use both Lua and the Arduino IDE on the node-mcu?

Tags: esp8266, arduino

I've been playing around with two node-mcu boards uploading Lua scripts via ESPlorer on one and uploading code built from C++ via the Arduino IDE.

I've come to a point where I have preference for Lua but also a C++ library intended for Arduino (GxEPD) that I'd like to use.

Are the Lua and Arduino options on the node-mcu mutually exclusive, or can I interface between them somehow? In other words, can I call the GxEPD library from Lua or, alternatively, call installed Lua code from C++?

Comment: There appears to be a way to send information in one direction at least: https://github.com/IRNAS/SimpleArduinoESP-Lua.  Here the serial interface is used to evaluate Lua code, setting a variable that is then picked up by a Lua timer callback. It's pretty crude, and really I need the communication to go the other way ut might do the job if I'm able to parse command return values.

Comment: Do you mean on the same device at the same time?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I did mean the same device, and I see now that the project I referred to is two devices, so that's a no-go. I'm guessing the only way to go will be to port the library I want to use to Lua, but if there is a simpler option I'll be happy.

Comment: I can't see any other way other than porting the library - though, if it's the one that I found with that name, that won't be a trivial task at all!